# rails presence conditional validation between 2 fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

first rails program here. I would like to go a little further than req'd and, for instance, allow entries into an address book accept a first name OR a last name or both. In other words, I would like to validate_presence_of first OR last, and only throw an exception if both are missing, a super easy thing to do in C++, but what would syntax look like in Ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couldn't you just run a conditional validates presence of last_name if first_name is blank?  If the first name is NOT blank, then the validation won't run, but if it is blank then it makes sure the last_name is not also blank...

```
validates :last_name, :presence => true, :if => "first_name.blank?"
```

Comment: New syntax ```validates :last_name, presence: true, if: "first_name.blank?"```

Answer (score 1):

You want a custom validation method as described [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but it took me places I didn't understand yet. I will have to learn all the ramifications of the error generation/handling, but you're right that custom validations will definitely allow me the power of the kind of c++ logic that I am used to, once I figure it out.